# How to exclude non-project directories from error checking?

Tags: typescript, webstorm

I see that my project triggers quite a lot of TypeScript errors outside of my code (for instance in in `<project root>\node_modules\webpack-chain\types\index.d.ts`).

I have [excluded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) `node_modules` in `<project root>/tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "extends": "@quasar/app/tsconfig-preset",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

Is there a special way I need to instruct WebStorm to skip this directory?

Comment: This should be the default, but in case it's not: Right click the `node_modules` directory in the tree and select Mark directory as -> Library Root or Excluded

Comment: @EmanuelVintilă: there is `library root` next to `node_modules` on the tree view. I can mark it as "Not Exliuded" so I guess it is in the state you refer to. It just looks like ESLint does not take that into account (?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the errors come from the Typescript compiler service, not from the IDE. And the compiler (1) is not supposed to respect IDE exclude filters (2) doesn't apply the filters defined in `tsconfig.json` (where node_modules are excluded by default) to files referenced from included files.
See https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exclude:

> Important: exclude only changes which files are included as a result of the include setting. A file specified by exclude can still become part of your codebase due to an import statement in your code, a types inclusion, a /// <reference directive, or being specified in the files list.
> It is not a mechanism that prevents a file from being included in the codebase - it simply changes what the include setting finds.

So, if the file the issue is reported against is included (via the imports chain) into any of your project `.ts` files, you will see the compiler errors reported for it